# Required vaccinations for New Zealand

Tags: health, new-zealand, oceania, vaccinations

Are there any required vaccines to travel to New Zealand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There are no required vaccines** to enter the country, either as a visitor or with a work visa. In the second case, along with your application you will be asked to provide a couple of medical tests and in some cases a chest X-Ray (but only if you come from a high incidence TB country).

Answer (score 3):

If you're just visiting, odds are you'll be fine.  However, there is a small risk of contracting Hepatitis A from contaminated drinking water, and Hep B from sexual contact, needles/tattoos and the like.  You'll also want your regular shots to be up-to-date - tetanus, MMR, polio and so on.

More information is available on the [CDC website's page for New Zealand](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/new-zealand).

However, as with all medicine, **DO consult with a medical professional** before choosing to take/reject medicine.

Comment: I'm moving to NZ. Some countries require vaccines in order to enter the country, so I was asking about this - health regulamentation -, not about recommendation. But thanks for the info, anyways!

Comment: @Roberto Moving is a different story, and off-topic for this site (immigration/expat question).  You'll be told as part of the immigration process which ones you're required (I moved to NZ in 1994) - usually it's MMR, Hep A/B and maybe one or two others.

Comment: Thank you. I got the visa already, but couldn't find this information.